# Returning sum of first value in a Python Dictionary

Tags: python

Hi I have a dictionary where I want to return the sum of the first value for each key

```
mydict= {'buddy': [9, 14, 'dog'],
             'snowball': [3, 10, 'cat'],
             'bella': [5, 3, 'dog'],
             'polly': [2, 3, 'bird']}
```

So I want the sum of the first value so sum should equal 19
Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use *sum()* in conjunction with a generator like this:

```
mydict= {'buddy': [9, 14, 'dog'],
             'snowball': [3, 10, 'cat'],
             'bella': [5, 3, 'dog'],
             'polly': [2, 3, 'bird']}

print(sum(x[0] for x in mydict.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
19
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you.But most efficient solution is of @Albert Winestein

**Code :**

```
mydict= {'buddy': [9, 14, 'dog'],'snowball': [3, 10, 'cat'],'bella': [5, 3, 'dog'],'polly': [2, 3, 'bird']}
   
print(sum([i[1][0] for i in mydict.items() ]))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want the first item, here is an approach using `zip` to transpose the values and `next` to get the first items:

```
sum(next(zip(*mydict.values())))
```

Output: `19`